# I have to reload my page alot of times because im getting a time Error

Tags: next.js, jwt, clerk

> JWT issued at date claim (iat) is in the future. Issued at date: Mon, 18 Mar 2024 17:56:52 GMT; Current date: Mon, 18 Mar 2024 17:56:44 GMT; (reason=token-not-active-yet, token-carrier=cookie)
> null
> ⨯ node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/dist/esm/server/authMiddleware.js (173:10) @ assertClockSkew
> ⨯ Clerk: Clock skew detected. This usually means that your system clock is inaccurate. Clerk will continuously try to issue new tokens, as the existing ones will be treated as "expired" due to clock skew.
>
> To resolve this issue, make sure your system's clock is set to the correct time (e.g. turn off and on automatic time synchronization).

I can't really resolve this issue.

I tried alot of things that chatGPT recommend me like set time to automatic and etc but nothing really worked.